# Setting an image.Source from a resource file

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, imagesource

```
private void SetCredentials()
{
    username = txtfromEmail.Text;
    password = txtpassword.Text;

    pictureLogin.Source = @"C:\Users\Sergio\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\emailwpf\emailwpf\ok.png";
}
```

I get an error: `"Cannot convert string to ImageSource"`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set source to `new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\Users\Sergio\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\emailwpf\emailwpf\ok.png"))`
You can set in XAML to string value, because registered converter is used under the hood;

Comment: And if I want to use the "/ok.png" form instead of the long string, how can I do that?

Comment: just creating Uri object, and specifying UriKind.Relative